# pyspark pandas_udf using partial functions went wrong

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, pandas-groupby, user-defined-functions

I defined a pandas udf function, and want to pass other arguments to udf function except pandas.Series or pandas.DataFrame. I want to use partial function to do that, but it went wrong. My code is in below:

```
from functools import partial

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("test")
spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 6), (2, 4)], schema=["x", "y"])

@pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def f(pdf, z):
    y = pdf.y * 2 + z
    return pdf.assign(y=y)

df.groupBy(df.x).apply(partial(f, z=100)).show()
```

and the traceback:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 140, in <module>
    df.groupBy(df.x).apply(partial(f, z=100)).show()
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pyspark/sql/group.py", line 270, in apply
    or udf.evalType != PythonEvalType.SQL_GROUPED_MAP_PANDAS_UDF:
AttributeError: 'functools.partial' object has no attribute 'evalType'`

Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: which spark distribution are you using . Because latest spark version doesn't seem to have any function as PandasUDFType .

Comment: The version is 2.4.3.@ Ajinkya Bhore

Comment: Creating an object of PandasUDFType like `PandasUDFType().GROUP_MAP`, I really don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please mention expected output in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot wrap the `pandas_udf` function in a partial function because `apply` won't recognize it as a `pandas_udf` anymore. Here the error says that the partial function doesn't have attribute `evalType`. That attribute is available only on the `pandas_udf` object.

Instead you could do something a bit different like having a function that returns the right `pandas_udf` for a given `z`:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 6), (2, 4)], schema=["x", "y"])

def f(z):
    @pandas_udf(df.schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def _internal_udf(pdf):
        y = pdf.y * 2 + z
        return pdf.assign(y=y)
    return _internal_udf

df.groupBy(df.x).apply(f(z=100)).show()
```

Comment: Works like a Charm! Thanks for this answer!! I spent hours trying out stuff :(                             
            I can also say that this answer works for SCALAR

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in pyspark 3.0 using the [grouped map Pandas function API](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#grouped-map).

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2), (1, 4), (2, 6), (2, 4)], schema=["x", "y"])

def f(pdf, z):
    y = pdf.y * 2 + z
    return pdf.assign(y=y)

partial_f = partial(f, z=100)

df.groupBy(df.x).applyInPandas(partial_f, df.schema).show()

+---+---+
|  x|  y|
+---+---+
|  1|104|
|  1|108|
|  2|112|
|  2|108|
+---+---+
```

The `@pandas_udf` decorator should not be used on the function declaration. Spark calls `pandas_udf` on your function behind the scenes when using the Pandas Function APIs.